# How do I use 'dune utop --watch'?

Tags: ocaml-dune

I would like `dune utop` or another OCaml top-level to pick up changes I do to my code while it is running. It seems as if `dune utop --watch` was designed to do that. Is that true? How do I make use of it?

In my experiments `dune utop --watch` ignored changes I saved to my module source code. Executing variations of `dune build` command didn't seem to help either.

Although apparently incompatible with `dune` I also tried `#use` and `#mod_use` directives without any luck: `utop` still didn't seem to pick up my code changes until restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. seems (once you have installed `inotifywait`)
 `dune build --watch` really starts working but `dune utop --watch` still does not pick up changes saved to source files..

`--watch` option is accepted as valid in `dune utop --watch` and `dune utop --help` does advertise it as supported but it seems this is just a bug in `dune` and `dune utop --watch` actually behaves exactly in the same way as simply `dune utop`.

It would have been a very nice option but apparently it is just not supported and might be impossible to support...